# Does Debian have any kind of virtual environment for make install?

Tags: debian, compiling, software-installation, dependencies

If someone used a Python virtualenv he knows we can run scripts in its own environment installing all necessary libraries which won't impact main python distribution.

Do we have something similar in a Linux (Debian) world for `make` utility?

1. Case 1: I downloaded sources and I know what dependencies I need. I
   put libraries somewhere in home directory and I explicitly say to
   `make` utility where to search them.
2. Case 2: I run some kind of virtualenv for `make` utility and I call there `apt-get install lib-required-dev` so downloaded libraries would be placed in this virtual environment and won't pollute my OS. And then I run `make`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case one is relatively easy, at least for some programs. Most source packages include a `configure` script which checks for the availability of needed libraries. These scripts will generally have options to specify search paths. For example `--lib-prefix`. That way, you don't even need to modify the Makefile yourself. Now whether, or not this will work will depend on how complex the dependencies are, but it's worth a try.

For option 2, you have the `chroot` program:

```
   chroot - run command or interactive shell with special root directory
```

`chroot` needs certain files and directories to be present. The details will depend on what exactly you need to do (e.g. do you need `/dev`? Do you need `/proc`?). You can get a minimal `chroot` environment like this (as root):

```
mkdir foo
cp -r /bin /lib /lib64 foo/
chroot foo
```

The last command will move you into the directory `foo` and run your default shell treating `foo` as `/`. The procedure I have outlined is a simplification. You don't need everything in `/lib` for example. You will also probably need more directories to be present depending on what you want to do. Finally, you can also use `mount bind` to link the directories into the `chroot` environment but not if you want it to be completely independent of your real OS.

An easy way of creating such a playground is to take a small partition and install a minimal system onto that partition. You can then simply make the `chroot` like so (always as root):

```
mount /dev/sda2 foo/
chroot foo/
```

Obviously, change `sda2` to whichever partition you installed your minimal system on. For more information see these links:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_Root
- https://wiki.debian.org/chroot

Comment: I haven't tried but it looks the most suitable solution for me

Answer (score 3):

terdon's answer is spot on.

Another, somewhat more involved but more durable approach, would be to actually create a virtual environment (virtualbox is my go to here.)  Create a new virtual machine with a basic/standard version of the OS you're using, save the state of that machine, and set about installing whatever dependencies as if you were on a regular system.  When you're finished compiling, you can then reset the VM back to it's original state.

It's worth noting that while you can absolutely do this headless i.e. in a remote, server environment, it's much easier to create the VM on a local machine (or a remote machine with a forwarded X session.)  Once you have a good base VM that you know how to access, you can then export the VM.

Comment: +1 Your comment about exporting the VM intrigues me. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I was thinking about it as the last solution. But I wanted to have something like chroot. But definitely your answer is 100% valid. Thanks.